# Putting line break using sed in bash, problems with regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

Hi everyone my data looks like this

```
  samplename 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  samplename2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
  >samplename
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  >samplename2 
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
```

[note - showing a line break after every 10 digits; I actually want it after every 200, but I realize that showing a line like that would not be very helpful].

I could do it using regular expression on a text editor but I want to use the sed command in the bash because I have to do this several times and I need 200 characters per row.

I tried this but got an error:

```
sed -e "s/\(>\w+\)\s\([0-9]+\)/\1\n\2" < myfile > myfile2
```

**sed: 1: "s/(>\w+)\s([0-9]+)/ ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern**

One more note - I am doing this on a Mac; I know that `sed` on the Mac is a little bit different from `gnu sed` . If you are able to give me the solution that works for a Mac that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain what's the meaning of "I need 200 characters per row", are there any others conditions you didn't show us?

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output using, say, "10 characters per row" instead of 200. You don't need to see how it works for 200 to be able to adapt a solution that uses 10.

Answer (score 1):

With your added request for a line break after 200 numbers, you are much better off using `awk`.

```
echo "hello 1 2 3 4" | awk '{print ">"$1; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {printf("%d ",$i); if((i+1)%2 == 0) printf("\n");}}
```

prints out

```
>hello
1 2 
3 4
```

If you want this to work *only* on lines that start with `hello`, you can modify as

```
echo "hello 1 2 3 4" | awk '/^hello / {print ">"$1; for(i=2; =NF; i++) {printf("%d ",$i); if((i+1)%2 == 0) printf("\n");}}
```

(the regular expression in the `/  /` says "only do this on lines that match this expression".

You can modify the statement `if( (i + 1) % 2 == 0)` to be `if( (i + 1) % 100 == 0 )` to get a newline after 100 digits... I just showed it for `2` because the printout is more readable.

**update** to make this all much cleaner, do the following.

Create a file call breakIt with the following contents: (leave out the `/^hello /` if you don't want to select only lines starting with "hello"; but leave the `{}` around the code, it matters).

```
/^hello/ { print ">"$1;
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
   {
      printf("%d ",$i);
      if((i+1)%100 == 0) printf("\n");
   }
   print "";
}
```

Now you can issue the command

```
awk -f breakIt inputFile > outputFile
```

This says "use the contents of `breakIt` as the commands to process `inputFile` and put the results in `outputFile`".

Should do the trick nicely for you.

**edit** just in case you really do want a `sed` solution, here is a nice one (well I think so).  Copy the following into a file called `sedSplit`

```
s/^([A-Za-z]+ )/>\1\
/g
s/([0-9 ]{10})/\1\
/g
s/$/\
/g
```

This has three consecutive `sed` commands; these are each on their own line, but since they insert newlines, they actually appear to take six lines.

```
s/^                  - substitute, starting from the beginning of the line
([A-Za-z]+ )/        - substitute the first word (letters only) plus space, replacing with 
>\1\
/g                   - the literal '>', then the first match, then a newline, as often as needed (g)

s/([0-9] ]{10})/     - substitute 10 repetitions of [digit followed by space]
\1\
/g                   - replace with itself, followed by newline, as often as needed

s/$/\
/g                   - replace the 'end of line' with a carriage return
```

You invoke this sed script like this:

```
sed -E -f sedSplit < inputFile > outputFile
```

This uses the

`-E` flag (use extended regular expressions - no need for escaping brackets and such)

`-f` flag ('get instructions from this file')

It makes the whole thing much cleaner - and gives you the output you asked for on a Mac (even with an extra carriage return to separate the groups; if you don't want that, leave out the last two lines).

Comment: Hi Floris, I just try it but its not working... the file stays the same

Comment: @user3049878 I just updated with a more useful answer - using `awk` is the right way to go once you start adding additional counters etc. It is much more flexible, and easier to understand.

Comment: Hi Floris, I am not an expert using awk, how do I set the input file???, I tried exactly what you put on my terminal but I got a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print ">" $1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, ((i-1)%10 ? FS : RS)}' file
>samplename
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>samplename2
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`fold` is your friend:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) /\1\n/' input | fold -w 100
```

Answer (score 0):

In double quotes the backslash is interpreted by the shell. Either one of these should work.

```
sed -e 's/\(>\w+\)\s\([0-9]+\)/\1\n\2/' < myfile > myfile2
sed -e "s/\\(>\\w+\\)\\s\\([0-9]+\\)/\\1\\n\\2/" < myfile > myfile2
```

PS, I added the terminating slash. You had a s/.../... instead of s/.../.../

PS, as I'm looking at your regexp, sed will complain no end. Try this.

```
sed -e 's/^\(\w\+\)\s\+/>\1\n/' < myfile > myfile2
```

MAC version, with 200 character limit (100 single digits and 100 spaces)

```
sed -Ee 's/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+) />\1\
/' | sed -Ee 's/(([0-9] ){99}[0-9]) /\1\
/g' < myfile > myfile2
```

First sed separates the character string from the number, the second splits the lines.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will try that, and what about the 200 character per line? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 200 characters, and I'll be glad to assist.

Comment: Hey Martin, I just tried the new command. I didn't work. I got my file exactly as it was before. So im guessing somethings wrong with the line break?? I am using a MAC OSX

Comment: My data actually has a lots of 0 and 1. And I am editing it to use it in another program, but this new file can only have 200 characters per row, so after the 200th character I need a line break and the 201 character in a new row and so on

Comment: Do you mean 200 characters including spaces (100 numbers and 100 spaces)?

Comment: Oh, MAC has a different sed, \n won't work. Sorry, you'll need gnu sed.

Comment: @Floris yes including spaces, 100 numbers and 100 spaces

Comment: Thanks again Martin! I am not sure I am writing your command in the terminal as you intended it. should i press enter every time I see the line break in the script you wrote? or how do I do that?

Comment: Like this: sed -Ee 's/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+) />\1\ENTER!!
/' | sed -Ee 's/(([0-9] ){99}[0-9]) /\1\ENTER!!
/g' < myfile > myfile2   ???

Comment: yes, in fact you can try to copy and paste it. you'll notice that there's a backslash before the new line, that's to satisfy sed. on linux it would be a \n, on MAC it needs to be \<ENTER>

Answer (score 0):

plain bash:

```
while read -r name values; do
    printf ">%s\n%s\n" "$name" "$values"
done <<END
samplename 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
samplename2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
END
```

```
>samplename
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>samplename2
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
```

assuming the samplename does not contain whitespace